# I have to add custom realm jar file to tomcat 7's lib folder. How will i do this on a shared hosting server

Tags: tomcat7, jdbcrealm

I have created custom realm jar file and have to add it to the tomcat server's lib folder for my custom realm to work. This works fine when i deploy my application on my local tomcat server. My question is how to add this jar to the server's lib folder on a shared hosting server, if i buy shared jsp hosting account. Is there any provision for doing so, and if not, what is the alternate to this.

Answer (score -1):

I don't expect any shared hosting provider will allow you to add an arbitrary JAR file to their shared lib folder. You may need to contact the hosting provider and ask/plead/beg them to do so, and in any case they may want (I should hope they do!) to look at the source to make sure you aren't doing anything unsound/unsafe/evil.

Comment: Well, for shared hosting you really won't find one: you either need to run your own Tomcat instance with full control, beg the hosting provider to run your own or use an existing realm implementation (possibly transform whatever authentication store you're using to let it me accessed by one of the existing built-in realm implementations).